# Redirect to welcome page on pressing back button in react Single page application

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a react single page application, so on pressing back button, its redirecting me to welcome page as expected. Now due to some requirement, I have to update the URL of the app in between and due to which if now I press back button, its first redirect me to old url page and then welcome page.
How can I control this behavior, means even after updating the URL, user should directly redirected to welcome page on pressing back button.

Comment: Which version of react-router you are using?

Comment: react-router version 2.8.1 @JahangirAlam

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it using react router, but you can use window.history.pushState() to solve your problem. In your third component add the following code into the render() method.

```js
window.history.pushState(null, null, '/your-welcome-page-url');
```

It will change the current url to welcome page url without reloading the page; and when you will press the browser back button, the browser will be redirected to welcome page.

Answer (score 1):

> I think you can make use of **react-router-dom** here. There is **Link** element available in **react-router-dom** which can solve your problem.
>
> For eg:, you can try something like this
>   `<Link to="/welcomePage" >Back</Link>`
>
> For more information, go through below document [react-router-dom document](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md)